# Failure installing npm dependency specified with full URL

Tags: heroku, ember.js, ember-cli

I have created an ember-cli heroku instance:

```
heroku create xxx-yyy-uuu --buildpack https://github.com/tonycoco/heroku-buildpack-ember-cli.git
```

And deployed to it:

```
git push heroku
```

But it fails:

```
remote: bower ember#^2.0.0        invalid-meta ember is missing "ignore" entry in bower.json                                                                                                                 [6/2258]
remote: bower ember#>=1.4         invalid-meta ember is missing "ignore" entry in bower.json
remote: bower ember#> 1.5.0-beta.3     invalid-meta ember is missing "ignore" entry in bower.json
remote: -----> Cleaning up node-gyp and npm artifacts
remote: -----> Building Ember CLI application production distribution
remote: 
remote: Missing npm packages: 
remote: Package: ember-cli-simple-auth-token
remote:   * Specified: git://github.com/jpadilla/ember-cli-simple-auth-token.git
remote:   * Installed: (not installed)
remote: 
remote: Run `npm install` to install missing dependencies.
remote: 
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ember CLI app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to xxx-yyy-uuu.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/xxx-yyy-uuu.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/xxx-yyy-uuu.git'
```

How can the npm package be installed?

### EDIT

My `package.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "xxxyyyuuu",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Small description for xxxyyyuuu goes here",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "start": "ember server",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.2.0",
    "broccoli-funnel": "^1.0.1",
    "broccoli-merge-trees": "^1.1.0",
    "broccoli-stew": "^1.0.4",
    "broccoli-unwatched-tree": "^0.1.1",
    "ember-cli": "1.13.13",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.5",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.1.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.2.4",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.1",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^1.0.4",
    "ember-cli-release": "0.2.8",
    "ember-cli-simple-auth-token": "git://github.com/jpadilla/ember-cli-simple-auth-token.git",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-data": "1.13.15",
    "ember-disable-proxy-controllers": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.4",
    "ember-link-action": "0.0.33",
    "ember-power-select": "0.7.2",
    "ember-simple-auth": "1.0.1"
  }
}
```

I am using a fully URL for `ember-cli-simple-auth-token` [because](https://github.com/jpadilla/ember-simple-auth-token/issues/111) version published to npm is too old.

Comment: can you post procfile ? and is your package.json valid ?

Comment: is your project installing locally without problem ?

Comment: @Bek: yes, project is installing (and running fine) locally: ember frontend, django backend (two different projects). Added `package.json`. No Procfile, since buildpack is specified manually.

Comment: have you tried specifying version for `ember-cli-simple-auth-token ` instead of full url ? or at least using shortform url `or at least jpadilla/ember-cli-simple-auth-token#branchName`

Comment: @Bek: updated question with rationale why I am using a full URL. But the reason should not matter, should it? It should be possible to use the same `package.json` in Heroku and locally, and a full URL **is supported** in a local package.json. What is the problem with a full URL in Heroku?

Comment: have you tried adding branchName also to full url ?

Comment: @Bek: tried changing the `git://` to `https://` and still did not work ...

Comment: @Bek: let me try branchname

Comment: you can always use short form of full url as it will default to github anyway `jpadilla/ember-cli-simple-auth-token#master`

Comment: @Bek: thanks, I'll try all possible combinatios, but I would like to know what is the problem behind this? What is Heroku (or the buildpack) doing to deviate from standard package.json behaviour?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99041/discussion-between-bek-and-gonvaled).

Answer (score 1):

No idea why Heroku is not allowing for full URLs in `package.json`, but @Bek pointed me to another [deploy platform](http://surge.sh/) which seems easier to use for static projects.

As opposed to Heroku, assets are built on the development host, which means if you can build your project locally, you can deploy: no buildpacks, no opaque and complex config. You do not get as much flexibility as you do with Heroku, but for simple setups this just works.